# Beans: How to properly manage a property affected by another one

Tags: java, javabeans

I have an Entity/JSF Managed Bean `Ticket` that represents a helpdesk
ticket.

It has a `status` property; when the status is set to `closed` I want to
change the value of the `closingDate` property to the current system time.
But I think that code should be contained in the bean, as each time the
ticket is closed the time should be recorded.

What would be the proper way to manage it? I have several ideas.

1. Make setter of `creationTime` private, and change its value when the 
   `status` setter is called. Fast and quick, but makes a setter change two
   attributes. Also, forces me to use JPA field access (not much of a problem
   as I am already using it, but still a limitation) and I am not clear of
   what will happen when the bean is serialized.
2. Make the `status` property a bound property as described in JavaBeans,
   and make the class a `PropertyChangeListener` to itself. Very formal, but
   a little overcomplicated to my likening.
3. Make setters for both properties private, and add a non-bean method
   `close()` that performs both actions. I would go this way but it can make
   me it complicated to work with JSF.
4. Do nothing. Keep the bean as dumb as it can and move the logic to the
   controller; cross my fingers hoping that nobody forgets to update both
   attributes.

I favour 1) or 3), but I would like to know if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if anyone can tell you the **proper** way to manage it, as arguments can be made for many different approaches just like you make them. To add to your list as a combination of 1) and 3), for example:

- Have the setter of `status` update `creationTime` when it `status` is set to closed and leave both setters public. Has benefits from both as I'm not aware of any downside to this from a JPA perspective.

What I would advice against however is having a *Entity/JSF Managed Bean*. I would recommend having two, an Entity bean and a JSF Managed Bean. This way your Entity bean can be kept as *dumb* as it can be, while your JSF Managed Bean will have *smart* methods like `close()` or `reopen()` and comprised of a series of *dumb* calls to the Entity bean. Also, you can do things like `persist()` in `@PreDestroy`. Easy to develop, easy to maintain, easy to make decisions. Hopefully you'll find this helpful.

Comment: Saw your answer a long time ago but I was busy and later forgot about it, sorry. The idea was to find a way of execute the `close()` method much like a `@PostConstruct` (but after the model was updated by the framework). The correct point is the separation of JSF and JPA beans; I was trying to avoid/soften it (using a wrapper for JSF instead of a fully different class), but there is no way to avoid. Using a different bean, the moment where you copy your data from the JSF to the JPA (or viceversa) is the moment to change how that data is represented.